# Appropriate Join/Connection For This Scenario?

Tags: oracle

I want to join two tables together which I have done

I also want to join them based on a condition, where a particular column has a specific value, and I also have done this successfully. I used an inner join and a where clause so far.

However, for this result set, I want to further filter it by selecting ONLY the columns where a particular string appears more than once for a set of columns, eg;

employee_ID and CERTIFICATE

I'd like to group where employee_id has CERTIFICATE count > 2. This is after I have joined the tables together using a where clause.

I am perhaps thinking of using a subquery in my WHERE clause (which is the 3rd line that is also last)

For further clarification, I want to display only employees who have a certificate count greater than 2. By certificate, I am referencing a table with a string 'Certificate' under a column 'Skill'. In other words, select only columns where the string 'Certificate' appears TWICE for a particular employee ID.

Comment: Give some sample data and expected output.

Comment: (1) please clarify whether you are using MySQL or Oracle, they are two separate database systems. MySQL is indeed owned by Oracle, but it is probably better to call it just "MySQL" to save on confusion. (2) please show us your database tables, e.g. from `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. Finally (3) would you add an attempt or your current work? That can be very helpful in understanding where you are going wrong.

Comment: @MT0: I suspect this is a MySQL question, not an Oracle question - I'd have tagged it the other way. Nevertheless, I hope the OP will clarify.

Comment: Ah no, I think you are right MT0 - didn't see the remark in the question body.

Comment: So here is further clarification. Imagine a table with a column "ACHIEVEMENT". Under this column there is the entry "CERTIFICATE". In addition, there is also a "NAME" column that links the name with the achievement.

I want to find all particular NAME entries where "CERTIFICATE" appears more than once.

Answer (score 1):

To get just the employee ids:

```
SELECT t1.employee_id
FROM   table1 t1
       INNER JOIN
       table2 t2
       ON ( t1.col1 = t2.col1 )
GROUP BY t1.employee_id
HAVING COUNT( CASE t2.skill WHEN 'CERTIFICATE' THEN 1 END ) > 1
```

Or, to get all the columns:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t1.*,
         t2.*,
         COUNT( CASE t2.skill WHEN 'CERTIFICATE' THEN 1 END )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY t1.employee_id )
           AS num_certificate
  FROM   table1 t1
         INNER JOIN
         table2 t2
         ON ( t1.col1 = t2.col1 )
)
WHERE  num_certificate > 1
```